# Redeploy all docker services by image on my swarm

Tags: docker, deployment, stack, swarm

my workflow is:

1. push code with git
2. Build docker image on my CI server ([drone.io](http://drone.io))
3. Push image to my private registry
4. Here I need to update all services in all stacks with this new image version from registry

Have anyone idea how to do it in a proper way?

I saw an official tutorial for [rolling updates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/) in docker docs.

```
docker service update --image <image>:<tag> service_name
```

But there is a problem that I don't know service and stack names.